# SUM formula with LEFT

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I've got a spread sheet. In column A I have area codes made up of numbers and letters. In column B  I have various numbers which correspond the the area code population. Column C is all the iterations of the two letter area codes with column D as their totals for the corresponding two digit area code.

```
AA99    49  AA      49
AB09    24  AB      65
AB02SE  23  AC      0
AB02SW  18
```

What I'm trying to find out is the population of each area code by looking at the first two letters of each area code (ignore the rest) AA, AB AC etc and find the total.

```
AA = 49
AB = 65
AC = 0
```

I haven't worked out an easy way to loop over all the area codes (there are about 30 of them) and work out the total population. Currently I'm using a horrible set of nested IF statements, in the form of

```
=IF(LEFT(C1,2)=C$1,B,"")
```

but I have a feeling there is an easier way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can help you

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B:B,(LEFT(A:A,2)=C1)*1)
```